# Why am I unable to access my page in my Windows Universal App?

Tags: windows-store-apps, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

How should I navigate between pages in a "Windows Store Universal App" **when my views are separated from the shared project**?

I implemented the same class of navigation of the templates...

[image: The error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access a class, in let's say your `Windows Phone` project, from the shared project, the class must be available in all other projects as well. So, create a `Products` in the `Windows` projects as well and then you'll be able to navigate to it.